# php function echo

Tags: php, function

I have:

```
$an = "1989";
$luna = "4";
$zi = "23";


function CalzulareZodie($date){
         list($an,$luna,$zi)=explode("-",$date);
         if(($luna==1 && $day>20)||($month==2 && $zi<20)){
              return "Varsator";
         }else if(($luna==2 && $zi>18 )||($luna==3 && $zi<21)){
              return "Pesti";
         }else if(($luna==3 && $zi>20)||($luna==4 && $zi<21)){
              return "Berbec";
         }else if(($luna==4 && $zi>20)||($luna==5 && $zi<22)){
              return "Taur";
         }else if(($luna==5 && $zi>21)||($luna==6 && $zi<22)){
              return "Gemeni";
         }else if(($luna==6 && $zi>21)||($luna==7 && $zi<24)){
              return "Rac";
         }else if(($luna==7 && $zi>23)||($luna==8 && $zi<24)){
              return "Leu";
         }else if(($luna==8 && $zi>23)||($luna==9 && $zi<24)){
              return "Fecioara";
         }else if(($luna==9 && $zi>23)||($luna==10 && $zi<24)){
              return "Balanta";
         }else if(($luna==10 && $zi>23)||($luna==11 && $zi<23)){
              return "Scorpion";
         }else if(($luna==11 && $zi>22)||($luna==12 && $zi<23)){
              return "Sagetator";
         }else if(($luna==12 && $zi>22)||($luna==1 && $zi<21)){
              return "Capricorn";
         }
    }
```

how can i echo the result of this function?

i've tried with:

```
$zodia=CalculareZodie();
echo "Zodia este: ".$zodia;
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You should turn on error reporting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the variables to the function, now, judging by the start of the function it takes a string with a date separated by dashes as an arguement so you'll need to do something like:

```
$an = "1989";
$luna = "4";
$zi = "23";

$date = $an . '-' . $luna . '-' . $zi;  //Construct the string from the outside variables
```

Then you do:

```
$zodia=CalzulareZodie($date); //Pass constructed string to function.
echo "Zodia este: ".$zodia;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function takes an argument. You are not passing one.

```
$zodia=CalculareZodie($somedate);
```

You've also misspelled it.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass argument. Also check the spelling `CalzulareZodie`

```
$zodia= CalzulareZodie('1989-4-23');
echo "Zodia este: ".$zodia;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the date as function's argument.

Also note that the variable declared outside the function are not available within the function. Either you have to declare them inside function or use [global variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

```
$an = "1989";
$luna = "4";
$zi = "23";


function CalzulareZodie($date){
         global $an, $luna, zi; // If you want
         list($an,$luna,$zi)=explode("-",$date);
         if(($luna==1 && $day>20)||($month==2 && $zi<20)){
              return "Varsator";
         }else if(($luna==2 && $zi>18 )||($luna==3 && $zi<21)){
              return "Pesti";
         }else if(($luna==3 && $zi>20)||($luna==4 && $zi<21)){
              return "Berbec";
         }else if(($luna==4 && $zi>20)||($luna==5 && $zi<22)){
              return "Taur";
         }else if(($luna==5 && $zi>21)||($luna==6 && $zi<22)){
              return "Gemeni";
         }else if(($luna==6 && $zi>21)||($luna==7 && $zi<24)){
              return "Rac";
         }else if(($luna==7 && $zi>23)||($luna==8 && $zi<24)){
              return "Leu";
         }else if(($luna==8 && $zi>23)||($luna==9 && $zi<24)){
              return "Fecioara";
         }else if(($luna==9 && $zi>23)||($luna==10 && $zi<24)){
              return "Balanta";
         }else if(($luna==10 && $zi>23)||($luna==11 && $zi<23)){
              return "Scorpion";
         }else if(($luna==11 && $zi>22)||($luna==12 && $zi<23)){
              return "Sagetator";
         }else if(($luna==12 && $zi>22)||($luna==1 && $zi<21)){
              return "Capricorn";
         }
    }
```

and

```
$zodia=CalzulareZodie("Enter your date here");
echo "Zodia este: ".$zodia;
```

Answer (score 0):

$zodia=CalculareZodie('specify date here');

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong.

1. You have a date argument which you are not passing in.
2. The variables are not accessible in the function and need to be set as global like this:

   function CalzulareZodie($date){

   global $an, $luna, $zi;

   // REST OF THE FUNCTION

   }